# Call Member Routes in ActionController::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'am new to Ruby and I have to write tests for a Rails Application.

My problem is that I don't know how can I invoke the `accept` action of the `FriendshipsController`

Here is the **`FriendshipsController`**:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationSocialController
  # ...

  # create method is getting called
  def create
    # accessing params[:user_id]
  end

  # accept method doesn't get called
  def accept
    # accessing params[:id] and params[:user_id]
  end
end
```

In the following test code I saw that the `FriendshipsController.create` method is called:

```
current_user = users(:users_002)
friend_user = users(:users_003)
@request.session[:user_id] = current_user.id
post :create, :user_id => friend_user.id # works fine
```

But how can I call the **`FriendshipsController.accept`** method?

```
current_user = users(:users_002)
friend_user = users(:users_003)
friendship_from_current_to_friend = create_friendship(current_user, friend_user)
# friend_user should can accept friendship request
@request.session[:user_id] = friend_user.id
put :accept, :user_id => current_user.id, :id => friendship_from_current_to_friend.id
```

The `put` call works without an exception, but `accept` of `FriendshipsController` is never called.

Here is the **routes.rb**

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  resources :users do
    # ...
    resources :friendships do
      # ...
      member do
        put :accept
        put :deny
      end
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

What is the correct way to invoke `accept`?

**Edit**

Here is an except of routes

```
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships/accepted(.:format)       friendships#accepted
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships/pending(.:format)        friendships#pending
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships/denied(.:format)         friendships#denied
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships/write_message(.:format)  friendships#write_message
PUT    /users/:user_id/friendships/:id/accept(.:format)     friendships#accept
PUT    /users/:user_id/friendships/:id/deny(.:format)       friendships#deny
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships(.:format)                friendships#index
POST   /users/:user_id/friendships(.:format)                friendships#create
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships/new(.:format)            friendships#new
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships/:id/edit(.:format)       friendships#edit
GET    /users/:user_id/friendships/:id(.:format)            friendships#show
PUT    /users/:user_id/friendships/:id(.:format)            friendships#update
DELETE /users/:user_id/friendships/:id(.:format)            friendships#destroy
```

Comment: How are you testing that it is invoked? The call looks perfectly fine

Comment: @papirtiger I've putted a `$stderr.puts 'create'` and `$stderr.puts 'accept'` on top of the controller methods. After that I can see it on the console, which method is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
Every friendship request consists of two corresponding friendship objects

On either

- the **right user**, i. e.`friend_user`, accepts the **wrong friendship id** or
- the **wrong user**, i. e. `current_user`, accepts the **correct friendship id**

the `accept` method will **not** called.

So if the right user accepts the right friendship id, the accept method will called fine. But this doesn't clarify why the accept method doesn't get called with a wrong input.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$ rake routes`

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
      friendships GET    /friendships(.:format)            friendships#index
                  POST   /friendships(.:format)            friendships#create
   new_friendship GET    /friendships/new(.:format)        friendships#new
  edit_friendship GET    /friendships/:id/edit(.:format)   friendships#edit
       friendship GET    /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#show
                  PATCH  /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#update
                  PUT    /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#update
                  DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#destroy
accept_friendship PUT    /friendships/:id/accept(.:format) friendships#accept
  deny_friendship PUT    /friendships/:id/deny(.:format)   friendships#deny
                  GET    /friendships(.:format)            friendships#index
                  POST   /friendships(.:format)            friendships#create
                  GET    /friendships/new(.:format)        friendships#new
                  GET    /friendships/:id/edit(.:format)   friendships#edit
                  GET    /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#show
                  PATCH  /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#update
                  PUT    /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#update
                  DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)        friendships#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                  users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                  users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)              users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)         users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)              users#show
                  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)              users#destroy
```

The output tells us that `accept_friendship` does not take a `user_id` param.

```
put :accept, :id => friendship_from_current_to_friend.id
```

Comment: Thank you! I run `rake routes` and I only get an empty list. But with `Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a` I was able to get these routes programatically. Please see my edit. I think that `:user_id` is needed otherwise I get an `No route matches {:user_id=>"2", :controller=>"friendships", :action=>"accept"}`

Comment: Can you please add your entire `routes.rb`? In your question `:friendships` are not nested under `:users`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was my mistake. Edited routes.db